# ES6 Nested Proxy for Get on Frozen Object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-proxy

I'm trying to deeply proxy the properties of a frozen object:

```
const a = Object.freeze([{ prop: 1 }])

const proxy = new Proxy(a, {
    get(target, property) {
        return new Proxy(target[property], {});
    }
})

console.log(proxy[0])
```

This produces a type error:

```
TypeError: 'get' on proxy: property '0' is a read-only and non-configurable data property on the proxy target but the proxy did not return
```

and I see that `get` proxies have the following restriction:

> The value reported for a property must be the same as the value of the corresponding target object property if the target object property is a non-writable, non-configurable own data property. - [es6 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-proxy-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-get-p-receiver)

Is there any way to have nested proxies on a frozen object?

Comment: One thing you should be aware is that Object.freeze is shallow

Comment: Also, this code creates a proxy on each `get` call? Is that intentional? Or do you just want to have a proxy object to a nested object?

Comment: The example just demonstrates the problem. The actual code memoizes `get` to avoid creating multiple proxies for the same property

Comment: Can't you just clone the `a` object and use it as the target for proxy?

Comment: I'd say don't freeze your objects, since the effect is shallow anyway. Rather than enforcing immutability, treat it as a guideline/policy in Javascript. When you use pure functions and combinators like lenses and appropriate data structures (recursive lists), mutations should hardly occur. Btw, if you have records in mind, `Object.prototype.seal` is a good tradeoff.